# Why does iptables accept packets on a given port, when it is closed?

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding

I am on Linux Mint.

I have a public static address assigned on my router and have manually forwarded a given port for torrenting, so not via UPnP, which I disabled both in the router, and the Transmission bittorrent application.

It works in a sense, that the Transmission shows the port is open. But when the Transmission is closed, so should be the port, as I understand it.

But there are new packets being accepted in `iptables`, although the Transmission is closed.

Why? What can I do?

Here is the `iptables -L -v`:

```
# iptables -L -v

Chain INPUT (policy DROP 7514 packets, 585K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  251 10040 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
 4330  371K DROP       icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 DROP       igmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
 4394  850K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
1324K  462M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 6751  415K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:56874

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1484K packets, 2391M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

and the same a minute later:

```
# iptables -L -v

Chain INPUT (policy DROP 7869 packets, 611K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  251 10040 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
 4330  371K DROP       icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 DROP       igmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
 4437  863K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
1324K  462M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 6983  430K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:56874

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1485K packets, 2391M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

As for the comments:

```
netstat -nap | grep <my port number here>
```

The command shows an empty result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not the job of iptables to drop a packet when the port is closed, that's the job of the normal network stack (as without iptables). (To be precise: the network stack does not just drop the packet, it also politely informs the other side that there is nothing listening.)

Just because iptables accept a packet does not mean there is anything listening.

Update: As mentioned in the comments, there is a risk. But that is not from accepting packets on the closed port per se, but from the *difference* in behaviour on this port compared to all other: Dropping vs. rejecting. The solution is to *not drop* packets on all other ports, but to *reject* them as the network stack would do:

If the packet is TCP, use `-j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`, for UDP and other port-based protocols, use `-j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable`. As every simple DROP is now splitted in two rules, it's best to create a new chain just for rejecting and jump to that chain wherever you want to drop before.

Use a portmapper like `nmap` to check the results.

Comment: No. Iptables drops packets to protect inner services that should not be accessable from the outside. If nothing is listening, there is nothing to protect.

Comment: So, it's not a security risk? That's what I needed to hear. Thank you very much. You seem like you really understand networking ;)

Comment: Well it is a risk. Because it's not dropping it like packets on other ports, an attacker can deduce that there may be something listening there in future, and continue periodically checking whether there is yet. If all other ports are blocked, then checking this one reveals that you exist at all.